# asp.net Dropdownlist inside a div with data-toggle=button

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have an ASP.Net DropDownList inside a div that has data-toggle="button", and when I try to select an option in the dropdownlist, it disappears instantly before I can make a selection. I have to hold the mouse button down to make a selection.

I believe it is somthing to do with the data-toggle on the parent div because when I remove that, the dropdownlist works normal.

Here is the straightforward markup.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ShippingTermsRepeater" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div class="form-group onewCustomer clearfix">
            <label>Shipping Terms</label>
            <div class="btn-group radioDouble shipTermsRadio" data-toggle="buttons">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <div class="btn btn-primary">
        <input id="ShippingTermsSelector" runat="server" type="radio" name="ShippingTermsGroup"/>
        <label for="ShippingTermsSelector">
            <span class="onewCurrency fontBlack"><asp:Literal ID="CurrencyLabel" runat="server" /></span>
            <span class="onewWHName fontBlack"><asp:Literal ID="WarehouseInternalNameLabel" runat="server" /></span>
            <span class="onewAccount"><asp:Literal ID="CustomerAccountCodeLabel" runat="server" /></span>
            <span class="onewTerms fontBlack"><asp:Literal ID="ShippingTermsLabel" runat="server" /></span>
        </label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ShippingTermsSelectList" runat="server" CssClass="form-control shippingTerms" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </div>
    </div>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: i believe that the data-toggle="buttons" adds a click action to the associated div as a visual cue for the radio button.  That would fire when attempting to select something on the DropDownList causing your issue.  I'm not giving an answer because it looks like you're implementing 2 distinct 'shipping terms selection' processes at the same time (a radio button toggle list and a drop down list) so I'm not certain what the end goal is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Depending on what radio button is selected, a DropDownList can then be displayed. Is there any Javascript override that can be added for the DropDownList click event to keep the opens displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding stopPropagation(); to the click event has fixed it.

```
$('select.shippingTerms').click(function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```